# gradle bootRun starts successfully but disconnects after some time

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, bootrun

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketOutputStream.writeWithNonBlockingRetry(SocketConnection.java:259)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketOutputStream.writeBufferToChannel(SocketConnection.java:247)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketOutputStream.flush(SocketConnection.java:241)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.flush(SocketConnection.java:119)
... 22 more
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was terminated in response to a user interrupt.
:bootRun FAILED
```

I have used

```
server.connection-timeout=-1
```

in application.properties but it still disconnects after some time.

I even used

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

in application.properties but to no avail.
What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any proof that this is a DB connection related issue ? if not, try checking the code for file reading, and catch the <i>java.io.IOException</i> on file reading part. it may help.

Comment: This seems to be Gradle related. Do you experience the same symptoms if you run your app's JAR file? with `java -jar ...`?

Comment: i have not tried that,but I highly doubt that's the issue.I'll give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

to

`spring.datasource.dbcp.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=SELECT 1`

Apparently there had been a renaming in springboot 1.4.